# How to mount multiple partitions

Tags: fedora, mount, hard-disk

Is there a way to mount multiple partitions, or even all partitions, of a disk with a single command in Linux? Is there, perhaps, an option that the `mount` command accepts that would facilitate this? I'm running Fedora 18; if I try `mount /dev/sda* /media/sda*` the operation fails.

Alternatively, can you suggest a script that I could put together for all my future uses?

I've come across some potentially useful posts that mention writing udev-rules; I'm not sure if that would be useful, though, since (as far as I know) the partitions on my main HDD already have those set up - which is evident by looking at the sidebar-list of accessible drives/partitions within my file manager.

To clarify, I'm simply trying to do something like '/dev/{sda1,sda2,...}', where each one of those would be mounted to their own directory with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a partition can be mounted to multiple locations.

And for your own purpose, I doubt mount itself supports so. But you could definitely use your own script,

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in $*; do
    echo mount "$x" "/media/${x##*/}"
done
```

And launch it with (Remove the `echo` before running it)

`./XX.sh /dev/sda* /dev/sdb*`

P.S: you should consider `udisks`, which would mount the partition to `/media/label_of_drive`

Comment: thank you warlock, and thanks to cinelli as well, I will look into udisks...it sounds like that's what I'm looking for! :D

Comment: `mount` will fail if folder in `/media` does not exist, better create them before: `for x in /dev/sda?; do mkdir "/media/${x##*/}"; mount "$x" "/media/${x##*/}"; done`

Answer (score 3):

The `mount` command will only map one device at a time, so whatever method you choose will have to call mount for each partition.

`/proc/partitions` will give you a list of what's detected:

```
# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0 1465138584 sda
   8        1 1465134488 sda1
   8       32 1465138584 sdc
   8       33 1465134488 sdc1
   8       16 1465138584 sdb
   8       17 1465134488 sdb1
   8       48 1465138584 sdd
   8       49 1465134488 sdd1
   8       64  156290904 sde
   8       65      96358 sde1
   8       66    4000185 sde2
   8       67          1 sde3
   8       69    2000061 sde5
   8       70   14996646 sde6
   8       71  135197527 sde7
```

This is where `fdisk -l` gets its information.  You could use this to do something like:

```
awk '$4 ~ /^sda[0-9]+/{print $4}' /proc/partitions | while read dev; do
    if findmnt /dev/$dev >/dev/null; then
        echo "/dev/$dev is already mounted.  Skipping."
        continue
    elif findmnt /media/$dev >/dev/null; then
        echo "/media/$dev is already a mount point.  Skipping /dev/$dev."
        continue
    fi
    mount /dev/$dev /media/$dev
done
```

Comment: Wealth of information in this answer.  For simplicity, however, I selected the simple for loop answer.  The background information in here, along with the awk scripting details, makes this an answer worth exploring for anyone interested in how `mount` works.  Additionally, as always, the man-pages are a must-read.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be booting the partitions at boot then you could add them to `/etc/fstab`. `man fstab` to see what all the different options are for the rows inside the configuration file. The columns should be organized as follows.

```
<file system>   <dir>   <fs-type>   <mount-options>   <dump> <pass>
```

If you are not going to be mounting them then look into using `udisks` or `udiskie`. You cannot mount two partitions to the same directory. You can mount one inside a `sub-directory` of an already mounted device though.

Comment: I'm not trying to mount them into a single directory, more like their own sub-directories within the /media/ folder: /dev/sda* /media/sda* ; also, I'm trying to chroot into them while mounted...but it's more of a general question, I suppose, about mounting multiple partitions without having to do a separate command for each partition; kinda like mount /dev/{sda1,sda2,...} or something like that.

Comment: You either have them auto mount at boot in `fstab` or `systemd.units` (`man systemd.mount, or you have the auto mounted upon being plugged in wish `udisks`. Or you have them auto mount upon access with `x-systemd.automount`. Other than that you're stuck to typing commands. Also, you should be mounting any additional partitions from inside the `chroot`. Only the partitions that you need in order to `chroot` should be mounted outside the `chroot`.

Answer (score 0):

Backup of current fstab:

```
#cp -a /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bk
```

process the output of **lsblk -f** using **sed** and **awk** and redirect output to fstab:

```
#lsblk -f|sed 's/\[SWAP]/swap /g'|awk '/(-)/{printf"UUID=%-36s %-23s %-7s defaults 
           0 0\n", $3, ($4==""?mnt"NR:$4), $2}'>/etc/fstab
```